# Hibernate HQL query with condition on second table

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql, conditional-statements, one-to-many

I have two tables (about football): Leagues and Teams which are in one-to-many relation. Now I want to get ALL Leagues but only with those teams which names start e.g. with "S".

So far I have this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select l from League l left join l.teams as t with t.name like :name order by l.id");
query.setParameter("name", "S%");
List<League> list = query.list();
```

This query returns all leagues, but also all teams. It looks like the condition is ignored.

All I want is just get ALL Leagues and just those Teams (specified by some condition) which belong to particular League. So it is possible to get a League with no Teams.

The mapping in League class is

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "league", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Team> teams;
```

and in Team class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "LEAGUE_FK")
private League league;
```

I am using Oracle DB. 
What is wrong with the query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract of `league.getTeams()` is to return the teams of the league. And the method will always return that, whatever the way you found the league.

Your query returns all the leagues which have at least a team starting with S.

The query you need is something like

```
select l, t from League l left join l.teams t on t.name like :name order by l.id
```

That should get you a `List<Object[]>` where the first element of each aray is a league, and the second is null or a team starting with S.

Comment: It works as you described but I still don't understand, why is not possible to directly select teams by some condition. So this is the only way how to filter teams?

Comment: The association between league and team is used to model the fact that league A has teams 1, 2 and 3. An instance of League represents a league in the database. Its teams collection represents the collection of teams of the league in the database. It doesn't represent what a previous query happened to select.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select l from League l where l in (select l from Team t where t.name like :name) order by l.id");
query.setParameter("name", "S%");
```

Comment: What's wrong with query? Its returns exactly what answer wanted: "All I want is just get ALL Leagues and just those Teams (specified by some condition) which belong to particular League." After light modification query will return response on second question: "So it is possible to get a League with no Teams".

Comment: 1. `select l from Team t where t.name like :name` doesn't make sense. 2. `where l in` won't work. And once you make that query valid, it will be slower than the one of the OP, and have exactly the same problem: it still returns leagues, and calling league.getTeams() will still return all the teams of the league.